# Imagemagick/ghostscript PDF error after update

Tags: php, centos, imagemagick, imagick

Running CentOS 6.5, just updated PHP/iMagick with the REMI repos and I'm now getting this error when trying to process PDF files:

```
PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pam" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -dUseCIEColor "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-320807xqpPIxdkvMk%d" "-f/tmp/magick-32080x_2jLbAXRyaJ" "-f/tmp/magick-32080lL2VmTkUoDy7"': -dname= must be followed by a valid token @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/256
```

I am running ImageMagick 6.8.9-7 with PHP 5.4.32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be some sort of bug in ImageMagick 6.8.9-7, downgrading to ImageMagick-last-libs.x86_64 0:6.8.9.0-1 fixed the issue.

In case anyone needs the command used:

yum -y --enablerepo=remi downgrade ImageMagick-last-libs